# Count occurrence of tuples with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I'm trying to convert a list of Python tuples that display product and cost to a list of tuples that display the cost and the count of products at a given cost.

For example, given the below input:

```
[('Product1', 9), ('Product2', 1),
 ('Product3', 1), ('Product4', 2),
 ('Product5', 3), ('Product6', 4),
 ('Product7', 5), ('Product8', 6), 
 ('Product9', 7), ('Product10', 8), 
 ('Product11', 3), ('Product12', 1), 
 ('Product13', 2), ('Product14', 3), 
 ('Product15', 4), ('Product16', 5), 
 ('Product17', 6), ('Product18', 7)]
```

I'm trying to create a function in Python that would render the below. i.e. The value 1 is rendered 3 times for three different products, hence (1, 3).

```
[(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 2), (8, 1) (9, 1)]
```

Comment: you just have to iterate through tuples and create a bucket of each value, increment the value in that bucket by 1  Its not too hard is it.  Do write some code mate

Comment: @BrijRajSingh - That is not the 'pythonic' way of doing it.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro: Brij's solution _is_ Pythonic: it's easy enough to do with a plain `dict`, but I agree that that technique has been superceded by  `Counter`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) could solve your problem:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(elem[1] for elem in given_list)
```

Output will look like this:

```
Counter({1: 3, 3: 3, 2: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 1})
```

If you want it in a list like you've specified in the question, then you can do this:

```
>>> list(c.iteritems())
[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 2), (8, 1), (9, 1)]
```

Comment: Simple. Easy. Efficient. Well answered!

Comment: Why use a list comp instead of `list(c.iteritems())`? BTW, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as it shadows the built-in `list` type, which can lead to mysterious bugs.

Comment: @PM2Ring - Thanks for the suggestions. I was trying to execute `list(c.iteritems())` but was getting an error. Now, I've realized it was because of the mistake I was doing given by your 2nd suggestion. Apparently, I found the mysterious bug. :P

Comment: Awesome, that worked great :) Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: I am curious to know about its complexities (runtime/execution time).

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way would be to use `map` and `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

l = [('Product1', 9), ('Product2', 1),
 ('Product3', 1), ('Product4', 2),
 ('Product5', 3), ('Product6', 4),
 ('Product7', 5), ('Product8', 6),
 ('Product9', 7), ('Product10', 8),
 ('Product11', 3), ('Product12', 1),
 ('Product13', 2), ('Product14', 3),
 ('Product15', 4), ('Product16', 5),
 ('Product17', 6), ('Product18', 7)]

cn = Counter(map(itemgetter(1), l))

print(list(cn.items()))
```

Comment: I am highly interested to know about runtime of each 4 Answer above. Please kindly share :)

Comment: @SaifulIslam, all the dict approaches are `O(n)` worst case , using list.count is `O(n^2)` . Doing a dict lookup is constant time, traversing the list with list.count is `O(n)`

Comment: So why ur approach is the fastest ? Sorry to ask simple questions (may be).

Comment: @SaifulIslam, , the complexity is the same it is just that map and itemgetter are done at the c level

Answer (score 0):

Another way is Defaultdict-

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(int)

d= [('Product1', 9), ('Product2', 1),
 ('Product3', 1), ('Product4', 2),
 ('Product5', 3), ('Product6', 4),
 ('Product7', 5), ('Product8', 6), 
 ('Product9', 7), ('Product10', 8), 
 ('Product11', 3), ('Product12', 1), 
 ('Product13', 2), ('Product14', 3), 
 ('Product15', 4), ('Product16', 5), 
 ('Product17', 6), ('Product18', 7)]
for i in d:
    dd[i[1]]+=1
counts  =  [i for i in dd.iteritems()]
print counts
```

Prints-

```
[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 2), (8, 1), (9, 1)]
```