# How to count occurrences of a string in nested tuple list?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a nested tuple list in python:

```
myList = [(12345, "John Doe"), (345678, 'Marie Doe'), (434566, 'Marie Doe'), (665533, 'Marie Doe'), (23456, 'John Doe'), (657332211, 'Amanda Doe')]
```

and trying to produce occurrences for names as two separate lists:

```
occurrences = [2, 3, 1]
names = ['John Doe', 'Marie Doe', 'Amanda Doe']
```

so far this one gave me a total number of items in my nested tuple, but not sure how I can produce the above:

```
Total = len(myList)
```

Could someone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You question is a little unclear, so to clarify you are looking to iterate over a collection and maintain 2 lists, one for the frequency and one for the actual strings?

Comment: Is `"Joe Doe"` a typo for `"John Doe"`?

Comment: ``from collections import Counter; Counter(x[1] for x in myList)``

Comment: @puffin, yes sorry for not being clear in my request above. I'm exactly looking for that.

Comment: @Aurele, I just edited. It was my bad sorry. Now it shows correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurrence of tuples with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749573/count-occurrence-of-tuples-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a `dict` where keys are names and values are their count in `myList`.

```
 myList = [(12345, "John Doe"), (345678, 'Marie Doe'), (434566, 'Marie Doe'), (665533, 'Marie Doe'), (23456, 'John Doe'), (657332211, 'Amanda Doe')]

# Initializing a dict with key: name and value: 0.
dict_name_count = {name: 0 for _, name in myList}

# Iterating over tuples in `myList`, picking name (the second entry in tuple) ignoring the number.
for _, name in myList:
    dict_name_count[name] += 1

print(dict_name_count)
# Results in: {'John Doe': 2, 'Marie Doe': 3, 'Amanda Doe': 1}

# To get separate lists:
names = list(dict_name_count.keys())
occurrences = list(dict_name_count.values())
```

Comment: this looks good. However, I need name and the number to be in two separate lists if possible. Would you be able to help with this?

Comment: Added that part.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

here is what I would do using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(myList).groupby(1, as_index=False).count()

occurrences = df[0].to_list()
names = df[1].to_list()
```

Outputs:

```
names : ['Amanda Doe', 'Joe Doe', 'John Doe', 'Marie Doe']
occurrences : [1, 1, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the names into a list, then just run counts of that list:

```
all_names = [elem[1] for elem in myList]
names = []
occurrencs = []
for name in set(all_names):
    names.append(name)
    occurrences.append(all_names.count(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    myList = [(12345, "John Doe"),
          (345678, 'Marie Doe'),
          (434566, 'Marie Doe'),
          (665533, 'Marie Doe'),
          (23456, 'John Doe'),
          (657332211, 'Amanda Doe')
          ]
namelist=[name[1] for name in myList]
names=[]
for name in namelist:
    if name not in names:
        names.append(name)

occurrences=[namelist.count(name) for name in names]
print(occurrences)
print(names)
```